# Simple NPM Question Re-updating local react project after other dev added new package

Tags: reactjs, git, npm, visual-studio-code, package.json

I just started working with vscode and npm/git. Someone on my team added a package and I did a pull to get his latest changes which put that package in my package.json file. When I ran the project I got errors for a module not being found. Obviously I need to install that package locally. Do I simply use npm install w/no arguments to get it? Or do I install it manually myself with npm install  and version info? I ask because I don't know if npm install w/no args will create a new package.json or cause any issues.

What is the correct way to get a new package installed that someone added in the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` can be run as many times as you like, and is what you should be doing here :)

`npm install`'s purpose is to get your `node_modules` folder up-to-date with whatever is written in `package.json`

So, if your colleague has changed `package.json` (by installing something new and pushing the change to git), you can just run the command again to get up-to-date.

---

Provided you haven't directly fiddled with any files in `node_modules` (this folder should be left alone), it is always safe to run `npm install` as many times as you like, even if nothing has changed.

Comment: perfect. that worked fine. I just wanted to make sure there were no undesirable side effects. thank you.

Comment: Makes sense, always worth checking :)